# Question on deploying backend expressJs @sendgrid to google cloud

Tags: express, google-cloud-platform, sendgrid

**Problem:**
I'm encountering a deployment issue with my MERN stack project on Google Cloud. The deployment consistently fails when trying to install the `@sendgrid/mail` package.

**Error Log:**

```
Step #2 - "build": Running "npm ci --quiet (NODE_ENV=production)"  
Step #2 - "build": npm ERR! Cannot read property '@sendgrid/mail' of undefined  
Step #2 - "build": npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:  
Step #2 - "build": npm ERR! /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-09-21T09_06_20_132Z-debug.log  
Step #2 - "build": Timer: Builder ran for 2.843129434s and ended at 2023-09-21T09:06:20Z  
Step #2 - "build": ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
```

**Attempted Solutions:**

1. Tried deploying using Docker to Google Cloud. Faced compatibility issues since I'm programming on a Mac, and Google Cloud's environment is Linux.
2. Attempted to ignore `node_modules` by adding it to `.gitignore`. This did not resolve the problem.

**Ask:**
How can I fix the deployment issues related to the `@sendgrid/mail` package on Google Cloud?

Comment: Please format the code of your question properly (using backticks and markdown) so it's easier to read and understand the question.

Comment: Already fixed! Thanks!